# php output loop array with switch gettype() give strange result

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array (
    [members] => Array (
            [name] => longtext
            [datum] => date
            [more] => Array (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
            )
        )
    [viewable] => 1
    [hierarchical] => 1
)
```

and when i try to loop the subarray $array['members']

```
foreach( $array['members'] as $k => $v) {    
    switch( gettype( $v ) ) {
        case "boolean":
            echo "boolean";
        case "array":
            echo "array";
        case "string":
            echo "string";
    }    
}
```

i expect output like

```
string string array
```

Instead i get the result

```
string string array **string**
```

I cant understand where the 4th string is coming.

When i try

```
foreach($array['members'] as $k => $v) {
    echo gettype($v);
}
```

the result is correct. Can someone explain me that? I also tried to change a member of the array to another type because i thougt php will merge same membertypes inside of the array but it doesnt.

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting that error is that you don't have `break;` on your `case`s.

On the third array element, it goes to `array` but since there is no break, it also goes to `string`

Your loop should be something like:

```
foreach( $array['members'] as $k => $v) { 
    switch( gettype( $v ) ) {
        case "boolean":
            echo "boolean";
            break;
        case "array":
            echo "array";
            break;
        case "string":
            echo "string";
            break;
    }    
}
```

Doc: [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: Damn, i know this soooooo long. I think i have to go to bed now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need a break statement in each your cases - otherwise you fall through:

```
foreach( $array['members'] as $k => $v) {    
    switch( gettype( $v ) ) {
        case "boolean":
            echo "boolean";
            break;
        case "array":
            echo "array";
            break;
        case "string":
            echo "string";
            break;
    }    
}
```